# OpenGL function to render RGBA values

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, render, rgba

I have RGBA values for a frame in a buffer. How do I draw the frame on the screen using opengl? Which function do I have to use? I'm using opengl-es 2.0.

gldrawpixels() is not available in iOS glKit.

Answer (score 1):

Use texture. glTexImage2D is probably available.
Then use this texture on full-screen quad.
That will involve some shader coding, when you could additionally process your colour data.

Comment: Is there any link that can help me with that? I'm still a beginner where opengl is concerned and I couldn't find good links which could help me with that.

Comment: Check this tutorial: [Render To Texture](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/). It should cover all you need!